# Google maps search box returns unexpected results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've implemented the places search box using this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Some searches in this example seem to return unexpected results.  For example (you can use the above example to reproduce these), if you search for "starbucks 32746" and select "starbucks Lake Mary, FL 32746, United States" from the autocomplete", it returns results from several zip codes instead of only 32746.

The same search on google maps displays the one location in 32746.

Another strange use case:

1. Search for "AT&T Stadium", and select "AT&T Stadium, AT&T Way, Arlington, TX, United States".  It displays the stadum as expected.
2. Search for "starbucks sydney" and select "starbucks Sydney, New South Wales, Australia"
3. Search again for "AT&T Stadium" and select "AT&T Stadium, AT&T Way, Arlington, TX, United States".  This time it returns several seemingly unrelated results, whereas I would expect the api to only return AT&T Stadium as in step 1. This how it works in google maps and I how I would think it would work in the api (although I understand there are differences in google maps and the api).

So what is going on here, and why does it work this way?  Is there anything I can do to make it emulate google maps' behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Places-Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) instead, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24899233/456814).

Comment: Gotcha... was just trying to help.