# Google maps api search returns unexpected results

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Using the example code at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

I find that when I type: DePaul University
and then choose the third one: DePaul University, North Kenmore Avenue, Chicago, IL, United States

it actually returns me a place named "The Theater School at DePaul University" where I would prefer getting just "DePaul University" which was what was bolded in the textbox.

Also when I type: Herzing University
and then choose: Herzing University Madison, Madison, WI, United States

It returns me many places... many of them hotels around the university. (???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Places-Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) instead